# Is unary operator +(variable) interpreted the same as Number(variable)?

Tags: javascript, unary-operator

I am wondering if these two examples are identical.

```js
    // sampler pack one
    const something = '5'
    console.log(typeof something)
    const thing = +(something)
    console.log(typeof thing)
    
    // sampler pack two
    const something2 = '5'
    console.log(typeof something2)
    const thing2 = Number(something2)
    console.log(typeof thing2)
```

I often use `Number()` to ensure some strings get interpretted as numbers, so is the unary plus operator identical under the JavaScript hood? Or is it faster? Or does it highlight any special conditions (particularly around large numbers or special kinds of numbers)?

I just ran this test here which shows them pretty identical:

```js
const unaryStart = performance.now()
const something2 = '5'
const thing2 = +(something2)
const unaryEnd = performance.now()
console.log((unaryEnd - unaryStart) + ' ms')

const numberStart = performance.now()
const something = '5'
const thing = Number(something)
const numberEnd = performance.now()
console.log((numberEnd - numberStart) + ' ms')
```

```
0.0049999999999954525 ms
0.0049999999999954525 ms
```

Comment: Seems to be implementation-specific. The results are near-identical on Chrome, IE, and Microsoft Edge, but Number() is consistently 9-10x slower on Firefox.

Comment: Per the stadard, both call internal `ToNumber`, but `Number` function makes a check for a case it was called via `new` operator. [Unary +](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-unary-plus-operator), [Number](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-number-constructor-number-value).

Comment: The edge case is of course that `Number` doesn't refer to the builtin function you expected, because someone overwrote the global or shadowed it locally. One cannot do that for operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both converts a string to `Number`, from MDN about [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus):

> [...] unary plus is the fastest and preferred way of converting something into a number, because it does not perform any other operations on the number.

From the standard ECMA 262 V 6, [unary plus](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-unary-plus-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

> *UnaryExpression* : + *UnaryExpression*
>
> 1. Let *expr* be the result of evaluating UnaryExpression.
> 2. Return ToNumber(GetValue(*expr*)).

From the standard ECMA 262 V 6, [Number](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-number-constructor-number-value) needs some more steps, because number could be called as constructor and that is checked in step 4, which needs some time.

> 4. If NewTarget is undefined, return n.

Comment: Fastest compared to what? That article makes no mention of Number().

Comment: @BoltClock, mdn states it, without a reference to a slower syntax.

Comment: Exactly. So is the reader supposed to take their word for it or something?

Comment: @BoltClock, as the standard describes, `Number` need some check which are necessary to definde the calling state of the function if a constrnctor is neede or not.

Comment: @NinaScholz I don't think it needs to find that, the compiler will resolve `new` calls to a different function than calls without `new`. I'd guess the slow thing is actually the global variable lookup for the identifier `Number`.

Comment: @Bergi, then even more, the unary plus is faster.

Comment: Thanks Nina for adding the TC39 spec info. I was going to edit my post to include those. Thanks to Teemu for finding those URLs.